# Ubuntu 12.04 microphone Acer Aspire One 150

Tags: 12.04, alsa, microphone, volume-control

The microphone was set to `0db` according to `alsamixer`. I had trouble seeing how to set to a sensible level.

Then I found how to set it but, but the microphone is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing pulseAudio volume controller:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Then start it from the HUD display and go to the input devices tab, select the "microphone" option from the drop-down, its "Internal microphone" by default, which most probably not the one attached somewhere on your screen, with a small opening. this worked on my acer aspire one when i wanted to use audacity.

Comment: I get   pulseaudio is already the newest version.

Comment: If I use an external microphone it works fine. I think this is a bug in 12.10 as it worked with 11.10

Comment: what do you see in the configuration when you run pulseaudio? can you confirm what device is selected...